# Kibana container to elasticsearch cloud auth err

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, certificate, ssl-certificate, kibana

I have a production instance of elasticsearch `5.6.9` deployed on [elastic.cloud](https://cloud.elastic.co).

WIth an http elastic all is OK but I would run a localhost kibana connected to that https instance!

I have tried:

```
docker run --name kibana-prod-user 
     -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=https://####.eu-west-1.aws.found.io:9243 
     -e ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=#### 
     -v /host/workspace/cert:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates 
     -p 3501:5601 --b kibana
```

but i get:

[image: auth err]

In my mount dir I have put the `cert.cer` of elastic cloud.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: May I ask why you don't use the Kibana instance that you already have in your ES Cloud cluster?

Comment: Because the goal is to define a uniformed way to connect to elastic through the environments and give to our customers and management a "branded kibana graph"

Comment: If you don't have the default user named `elastic` or `kibana` you also need to pass the `ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME` environment variable

Comment: No, i have the default user unfortunally

Comment: Since you're running a Kibana from Docker, why do you map your certificates in a folder called `/usr/share/elasticsearch`? Make sure you read this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/configuring-tls.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have find the solution, after understand that the error wasn't a certificate problem.

The right script for kibana 5.6.10 is:

```
docker run --name kibana-prod-provider -v "$(pwd)":/etc/kibana/ -p 3502:5601 --rm kibana
```

because the `ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD` envvar is not managed [by the docker file, only le URL is.](https://github.com/docker-library/kibana/blob/c59bd9585cbe6d62e1bd56c7975d2eb350dc11fb/5/docker-entrypoint.sh)

Then in the `$(pwd)` directory I have put this `kibana.yml` file:

```
server.host: '0'
elasticsearch.url: 'https://###.eu-west-1.aws.found.io:9243'
elasticsearch.username: elastic
elasticsearch.password: ###
```